# Shutdown message while running the program in Cocos2d for MacOS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

Currently i'm developing a Cocos2d application for `Mac OS X` using `xCode 4.2.1`.So my problem is,sometimes while running the program the system get's stuck and show me a message like this- `You need to restart your computer.Hold down the power button until it turns off.Then press the power button again`. After receiving this message i can't proceed further without restarting the computer.  What might be the problem behind this issue. Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 1):

What You get is called a **kernel panic**.

**Resolution**

> **Restart your Mac with a Safe Boot and see if the kernel panic happens
>   again**
>
> In most cases, kernel panics are not caused by an issue with your Mac.
>   They are most likely caused by an issue external to your Mac. If the
>   kernel panic doesn't happen again within a few weeks, you don't need
>   to troubleshoot further.
>
> 1. Depending on the model of Mac you have, restart one of these ways:
>      • Press and hold the Power button for several seconds to turn off your Mac. Then, press the Power button to startup your Mac.
>      • If you have a Restart button, press it.
> 2. As soon as your Mac starts up, hold down the Shift key to start up with a Safe Boot into Safe Mode. **Note:** If you are using a third-party
>      external keyboard and cannot start with a Safe Boot, try using an
>      Apple keyboard instead.
> 3. If your Mac has a kernel panic starting up, or while in Safe Mode, jump to the "Troubleshooting a recurring kernel panic" section of this
>      article.
> 4. If your Mac starts up without a kernel panic after a Safe Boot, restart your Mac by choosing Apple Menu > Restart…, then let it start
>      up normally. **Run Software Update and install all available updates
>      until Software Update reports "Your software is up to date".** Mac OS X
>      updates improve the tolerance for external issues such as malformed
>      network packets. For most kernel panics, this is all you have to do.

**Note:** It is possible, although very unlikely, that something on your network is sending your Mac malformed network packets which could cause recurring kernel panics. If the hardware and software on your Mac checks out as OK, check the devices on your network. Make sure your router's firmware is up-to-date, and that the router is not malfunctioning.  Refer to your router's manufacturer for service and support.

---

And You also can try to find the problem in `kernel.log`. Go to the console app in the utilities folder and then type this:

```
tail -f /var/log/kernel.log
```

It will print `kernel.log` file to Your console.

---

More information:
[Kernel Logs from the Command Line in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/04/20/console-logs-command-line-mac/).
[How to log a kernel panic](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2546).
[Kernel Panic](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3742).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this happens only when i run a particular application that i'm currently developing.

Comment: @Augustine did You try my second suggestion to look at `kernel.log`?